# DynamoDB Schema design with composite keys

Tags: database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use DynamoDB for the first time and after reading on best practices for designing a schema in DynamoDB, I have some questions which I can't seem to find the solution to.

I have a relational DB that have a structure like:

```
#org table
-------------------------------------------------------
orgID       |   orgAttributes
-------------------------------------------------------

#org -> dept team
-------------------------------------------------------
orgID       |   deptName        |   teamAttributes
-------------------------------------------------------

#org -> campaign table
-------------------------------------------------------
orgID       |   campaignID      |   campaignAttributes
-------------------------------------------------------

#campaign -> campaign group
-------------------------------------------------------
campaignID  |   groupID         |   groupAttributes
-------------------------------------------------------

#campaign -> customer list
-------------------------------------------------------
groupID     |   customerID      |   customerAttributes
-------------------------------------------------------
```

All of which is a 1 to many mapping to the child table. I read the docs from AWS and am planning to implement the use of composite sort key

My table design should look something like:

```
#dynamo attempt
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PK          |   SK                              |   attributes
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORG#orgID   |   METADATA#orgID                  |   orgAttributes
            |   DEPT#deptName                   |   deptAttributes
            |   CAMPAIGN#campaignID             |   campaignAttributes
            |   CAMPAIGN#CAMPAIGNGROUP#groupID  |   groupAttributes + list<customer>
```

Now the part I am confused is would there be 4 tables like:

```
org table   
{
    PK: ORG#orgID 
    SK: METADATA#orgID
    orgattribute1: 123
    orgattribute2: 123
}

dept table  
{
    PK: ORG#orgID 
    SK: DEPT#deptName
    deptattribute1: 123
    deptattribute2: 123
}

campaign table
{
    PK: ORG#orgID 
    SK: CAMPAIGN#campaignID    
    campaignattribute1: 123
    campaignattribute2: 123
}

campaign group table
{
    PK: ORG#orgID 
    SK: CAMPAIGN#CAMPAIGNGROUP#groupID    
    customerList: { object containing list of customers }
    campaigngroupattribute1: 123
    campaigngroupattribute2: 123
}
```

or one table only for org with everything else as a object in it's json:

```
org table
{
    PK: ORG#orgID 
    SK: METADATA#orgID
    orgattribute1: 123
    orgattribute2: 123
    dept: {dept object}
    campaign: {campaign object}
    campaigngroup: {campaign group object}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the data volume that the application handles for each entities you can decide whether you need to use single or multiple DynamoDB table. So with your current requirement without doubt go ahead with single dynamo table.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PK                                                  |   SK                              |   attribute 1               |   attribute2              |     ...    | attributeN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORG#orgID                                           |   METADATA#orgID                  |   OrgAttribute 1 Value      |   OrgAttribute 2 Value    |
ORG#orgID                     ̥                      |   DEPT#deptName                   |   deptAttribute 1 Value     |   deptAttribute 2 Value   |
ORG#orgID                                           |   CAMPAIGN#campaignID             |   campaignAttribute 1 Value |   ...
ORG#orgID#CAMPAIGN#campaignID                       |   CAMPAIGNGROUP#groupID           |   groupAttribute 1 Value    |   ...
ORG#orgID#CAMPAIGN#campaignID#CAMPAIGNGROUP#groupID |   CUSTOMER#customerID             |   customerAttribute 1 Value |   ...
```

In this way you can achieve 1 to Many relationship. Also in the same way you can integrate some more entities like Employees, products etc... in future

For example: If you want all the CAMPAIGNGROUP under a particular campaignID. Then you can directly query (efficient way) the data using the PK as `ORG#orgID#CAMPAIGN#campaignID` and SK using `begin_with('CAMPAIGNGROUP#')`

Similarly you can check other requirement with this table structure. Also check DynamoDB LSI and GSI features for indexing data and querying data efficiently.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, was having doubt of a single table design. and thank you for the suggestion on the campaignID too!